# Fedex Shipping Method Issue in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, fedex

I have configured fedex shipping method in admin panel,
I have entered valid account id, meter number, key, password sent from Fedex to registered Email.

[image]

There is no option showing in checkout page shipping method section after configurations. I can see below response in log file.

```
[result] => stdClass Object
(
    [HighestSeverity] => ERROR
    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Severity] => ERROR
            [Source] => crs
            [Code] => 803
            [Message] => Meter number is missing or invalid.  
            [LocalizedMessage] => Meter number is missing or invalid.  
        )

    [Version] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ServiceId] => crs
            [Major] => 10
            [Intermediate] => 0
            [Minor] => 0
        )
)
```

I have used valid credentials, I tried the websearch with above error code and error message but no solution found.

What i am doing wrong with this? 
Any help much appreciation!

Thanks

Comment: `Meter number is missing or invalid`. (please recheck meter number sent on email by fedex developers account)

Comment: Yes, I have double checked meter number which i have in email.

Comment: Hope you have enable sandbox. The module i'm using has a dropdown option to enable it.

Comment: Please check my configuration image attached with question.

Comment: i know this is very old but im having the same issue in 1.9.3 now